# Calculation in Mysql Based on Matches

Tags: mysql

I am having Following Table

```
userid | Field1 | Field2 | Field3
1      | S      | M      | M
2      | M      | A      | B
```

Now  i am having a set like(S,M,A).

I want to give 2 point. the Field1, Field3 ,Fields this three contains any one value from given set .the point will be 6. if any one Field matches the points will be 2.

For Example output should be

```
userid | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | points
1      | S      | M      | M      | 6
2      | M      | A      | B      | 4
```

I have used the Followig Query but it doesnot return any value

```
SELECT @hqp,
       UserId 
  FROM (SELECT @hqp := 0, 
               IF( Field1 IN ('S','M','A'), @hqp := @hqp +2, @hqp),
               IF( Field2 IN ('S','M','A'), @hqp := @hqp +2, @hqp),
               IF( Field3 IN ('S','M','A'), @hqp = @hqp +2, @hqp),
               @prev:=A.user_id as UserId 
          FROM users as A 
                 JOIN (SELECT @hqp := 0, @prev:=0) as B) as M
```

But it returns `@hpq` as 0 for every Row. Can any one help.

Comment: `@hqp := 0,` should be in FROM clause, you are reassigning it for every row.

Comment: I don't understand how you derive that result. Surely it should be (4 and 2) or (6 and 4)

Comment: I also agree that it should be 6 and 4

Comment: yes, it should be 6 and 4 only .. How can i get from my query , could pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT userid,
       Field1,
       Field2,
       Field3,
       (IF(Field1 IN ('S','M','A'),2,0)+
        IF(Field2 IN ('S','M','A'),2,0)+
        IF(Field3 IN ('S','M','A'),2,0) ) points
  FROM users
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/322410/1

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design, so see normalisation.

However, something like the following will work...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(userid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Field1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,Field2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,Field3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'S','M','M'),
(2,'M','A','B');

SELECT userid
     , SUM(f IN ('S','M','A'))*2 points 
  FROM
     ( SELECT userid,field1 f  FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT userid,field2 FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT userid,field3 FROM my_table ) x
 GROUP 
    BY userid;
+--------+--------+
| userid | points |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      6 |
|      2 |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```